# How to delete utun0 in my macos?

Tags: mac-osx, interface

ifconfig:
utun0: flags=8050<POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
inet6 fe80::a3d5:45cd:d66b:6bd5%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x12
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>

route:
fe80::a3d5:45cd:d66b:6bd5%utun0         link#18                         UHLI              lo0

---

sudo /sbin/ifconfig utun0 delete
ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCDIFADDR): Can't assign requested address